# How to implement maximum 3 try for requesting resource in rest api java

Tags: java, jbpm, httpconnection, rest

I want to do something like, I should allow user to request for 3 times. After that only it should throw error.

I have go through many articles, they said to use something like :

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  try
  {
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    if(count<3)
    {
        count++;
        countinue;
   }
}
```

I tried implementing this, but this executed in just one request.

What I want to do is that for each request made it should check for count.

e.g when I make a request through postman once, it should check for one.

When I again made request through postman it should increase count to 2 and at last  for 3rd time it should throw error.

Here is the sample code here :

```
    @PUT
    @Path("/{containerId}/assignnexttask")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response somemethod(@Context HttpHeaders headers, @PathParam("containerId") String containerId,
            @RequestBody String payload) throws JSONException {
        Variant v = RestUtils.getVariant(headers);
        String contentType = RestUtils.getContentType(headers);
        MarshallingFormat format = MarshallingFormat.fromType(contentType);
        // for loop is for maximum 3 attempts ,
        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try { 
              //here is some code 
            }
            catch(Exception e )
            {
               if(count<3)
               {
                  count++;
                  continue;
               }
             }
         }
     }
```

Hope i am able to explain.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: looks like count variable is declared at class level. Rather you should re-initialize it as the first line of method.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, it is declared inside method only.By mistake i removed here.

Comment: Can you show updated code please? To help you better?

Comment: updated.Please check

Comment: As per current code it should be doing like if you make a request and there is some error,  it tries three times internally and then throws error. While what you want is that if use make a request and there is some error it should wait for another request from use and keep on trying till 3 request from use and then throw the error. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: Yes , Absoultely Correct .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219795/discussion-between-gaurav-jeswani-and-neha).

Comment: So let's say on first request if there is error what response you expect from method? Is it null?

Answer (score 1):

Rather you should updated your code as below (sample pseudo code). (Assuming that if there is error on first and second request `null` should be returned as `Response`).

So you need to maintain the static variable. And after error successful request or before error throw, variable should be re-initialized to 0 to make it ready for subsequent requests.

```
//class level variable to count the error
private static int count = 0;

    @PUT
        @Path("/{containerId}/assignnexttask")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response somemethod(@Context HttpHeaders headers, @PathParam("containerId") String containerId,
                @RequestBody String payload) throws JSONException {
            Variant v = RestUtils.getVariant(headers);
            String contentType = RestUtils.getContentType(headers);
            MarshallingFormat format = MarshallingFormat.fromType(contentType);
            // for loop is for maximum 3 attempts ,
            try { 
                  //here is some code

                   // count = 0 to make it ready for next request if no error
                   count = 0;
                   // Response data
                   return response;
            }
            catch(Exception e ) {
                   if(count<3)
                   {
                      count = count + 1;
                      return null;
                   }
                   // count = 0 to make it ready for next request
                   count = 0;
                   throw e;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
  try
  {
     doSomething();
     break;
  }
  catch(Throwable e)
  {
    if(i==2)
    {
       throw e;
    }
  }
}
```